# Using JQuery UI drag, drop, and resize with SVG elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-svg

I have this working for `DIV` elements, cause that is easy enough. You can see this working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/18erqbqv/23/

My goal is to perform the same activities with an `SVG` element. This is proving to be more difficult.

My current working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/18erqbqv/37/

I have moved to using the jQuery SVG plugin found here: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html It has helped a great deal.

Here are the basics:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parts">
  <div class="square draggable">
  </div>
  <div class="hex draggable">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="drawzone">
  <div class="droppable">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parts {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 7px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}

.draggable {
  display: inline-block;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: rgba(128, 255, 128, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
}

.hex {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.hex polygon {
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.65);
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.dropped {
  font-family: Arial, san-seriff;
  display: table;
}

.dropped .label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.selected {
  border-color: #f30;
}

.selected polygon {
  stroke: #f30;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
  $("#parts div.hex").svg(40, 40);
  var hex = $(".hex").svg('get');
  hex.polygon([
    [19, 1],
    [38, 9],
    [38, 30],
    [19, 38],
    [1, 30],
    [1, 9]
  ], {
    fill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.65)',
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 1
  });
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: "move",
    containment: ".droppable",
    zIndex: 1001,
    appendTo: ".droppable"
  });
```

This code all appears to work well. It's the droppable that gets tricky.

```
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      var pos = ui.position;
      var $obj;
      if (ui.helper[0].nodeName !== "DIV") {
        $obj = ui.helper.closest("div").clone();
      } else {
        $obj = ui.helper.clone();
      }
      var c = $(".dropped").length;
      if (dropSnap) {
        pos.top = Math.round(pos.top / 10) * 10;
        pos.left = Math.round(pos.left / 10) * 10;
      }
      c++;
      if ($obj.is(".square")) {
        $obj.removeClass("draggable");
        $obj.addClass("dropped");
        $obj.css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: pos.top + "px",
          left: pos.left + "px"
        });
        $obj.attr("id", "square-" + c);
        $obj.html("<span class='label'>" + c + "</span>");
      }
      if ($obj.is(".hex")) {
        $obj[0].classList.remove("draggable");
        $obj[0].classList.add("dropped");
        $obj.attr("id", "hex-" + c);
        var hex = $obj.find("svg").svg().svg('get');
        var texts = hex.createText();
        hex.text(14, 24, texts.string(c), {
          class: 'label'
        });
      }
      $obj.on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("Clicked: ", e.target.nodeName);
        if ($(".selected").length) {
          $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        }
        var self;
        if (e.target.nodeName === "polygon" || e.target.nodeName === "text") {
          self = $(e.target).closest("div.hex");
        } else {
          self = $(this);
        }
        console.log("Self: ", self[0].nodeName, self[0].innerText);
        self[0].classList.add("selected");
        self.draggable({
          containment: 'parent',
          grid: [$(".grid").data("size"), $(".grid").data("size")]
        });
        self.resizable({
          handles: "ne, nw, se, sw",
          grid: $(".grid").data("size"),
          ghost: true,
          stop: function(e, ui) {
            console.log("Resize Stopped on ID: " + $(this).data("obj").id);
            $(this).data("obj").width = ui.size.width;
            $(this).data("obj").height = ui.size.height;
          }
        });
      });
      $obj.data("obj", {
        id: c,
        label: $obj.text(),
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left,
        width: $obj.width(),
        height: $obj.height(),
        layer: $obj.zIndex() - 1000,
        color: $obj.css("background-color")
      });
      $obj.dblclick(function() {
        var title = $obj.text() !== "" ? $obj.text() + " Properties" : "Object Properties";
        var label = $obj.text();
        var color = $obj.css("background-color");
        var layer = $obj.zIndex() - 1000;
        $("#item_dialog").dialog("option", "title", title);
        $("#change_item_label").val(label);
        $("#change_item_color").text(color).css("background-color", color);
        $("#change_item_layer").val(layer);
        //$("#item_dialog").dialog("moveToTop");
        $("#item_dialog").dialog("open");
      });
      $obj.appendTo(".droppable");
```

Any advice would be super helpful. If there is a better way to do this, such that I can make a hexagon shaped `div`, I would love to know. I may have also buried my head too deep in to see the issue. I also recognize the resizable will be a harry beast, so I am really just working on showing that the item is selected and enabling draggable.

Comment: There's apparently a whole site dedicated to making hexagon divs with CSS: http://csshexagon.com/ (not sure if this is actually helpful)

Comment: Tried that https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/18erqbqv/29/ worse issues. Namely I can't create a border on all sides the hexagon because I'm using the border to create the fill color

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg I stand correct! I got a chance to look over the site you suggested and this does have a border method. Thanks, I will review this more! You may have set me on the right path.

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg a step in a better direction. As you can see: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/18erqbqv/39/ Some interesting results on resize! :)

Comment: "Interesting" indeed, haha. Perhaps look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelperfect/M52QZ/71/ (which I got from [here](http://creative-punch.net/2014/01/perfect-css-hexagons-size-using-transform-calc/) when searching for "hexagon css percentage". Perhaps you can incorporate their proportional way of doing hexagonal units to have yours work on resize.

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg Looks promising and I see what they are doing there. Hopefully I can adjust the Width and Height in the `resize`. So will give that a go.